# How to make randomly placed ellipses loop in p5.js?

Tags: for-loop, p5.js

I'm trying to make a loop in p5.js that will draw small ellipses across the canvas. I've done something like this before, but the code was different.
There, when I wanted to try a loop, all I had to type was:

```javascript
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {}
```

The manual I'm using (*Make: Getting Started with p5.js*) tells me that the code to do this is similiar. This was an example it gave for drawing a bunch of lines:

```javascript
    for (var i = 20; i < 400; i += 8) {
       line(i,40,i+60,80)
    }
```

However, when I enter this code to even test it, it doesn't work. Can someone explain how to draw multiple small ellipses on the screen (I have variables set in place for the x and y coordinates of the ellipses so that they will be random)?

EDIT: This is a more full version of the code:

```javascript
    function draw() {
        noStroke();
        fill(fishCr,fishCg,fishCb);
        arc(ellX,ellY,ellW,ellH,0,180);
        arc(ellX+5,ellY-10,ellW/1.5,ellH/1.5,arcEl,50);
        arc(ellX-45,ellY+20,ellW/1.5,ellH*1.5,340,110);
        arc(ellX-60,ellY-10,ellW/1.5,ellH*2,arcT,40);
        fill(0,200,255,0.5); //this is the start of the code in                 
                             //question
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            ellipse(bubX,bubY,5,5);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
createCanvas(500, 500);

function setup() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    ellipse(random(0, width), random(0, height), 5);
  }
}
```

This creates a Canvas and draws 200 small circles at random locations.
Is this waht you are looking for?

Comment: this is better, but I can't change their transparency or the code stops working. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @KatK If you have a follow-up question, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question post.

Comment: `fill(0,200,255,0.5);` This looks fine to me. The error should be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to be more specific than saying it doesn't work. What exactly happens? What do you see in [the JavaScript console](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools)?

You should also read up on a tutorial on `for` loops. [Here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/for-loops) is one I wrote for Processing, but the basic ideas are the same.

Your first `for` loop starts at `0` and increases by `1` until it reaches `200`. Your second `for` loop starts at `20` and increases by `8` until it reaches `400`.

Also note that you have an extra opening curly brace `{` in your second `for` loop.

If you still can't get it figured out, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Good luck.

**Edit:** Take a look at your `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  ellipse(bubX,bubY,5,5);
}
```

Here you're drawing 200 circles, but you're drawing all of them at the same location, based on the `bubX` and `bubY` variables. You probably want to pass in random values here instead of the same variables every time.

Comment: I edited it to show my full code. In it's current iteration, it does not add small bubbles at random places on the screen, which is what I want it to do. The console doesn't say anything because I didn't tell it to.

Comment: @KatK The console will also include errors, not just print statements. Also, please try to post a [mcve] instead of your entire project. But see my edited answer for an explanation about what's going on.